# Way for members to block specific community members from commenting/answering posts?

Tags: feature-request, comments

I've recently had one member in particular who wastes hours of my time asking/commenting about my posts without contributing anything productive towards answering them. I don't want to appear rude to other members *(who obviously wouldn't be aware of the history)*, so I feel obligated to respond to each comment.

In addition, I've noticed that once this member starts participating I am significantly less likely to get input from other members *(probably because they either assume that he's solving the problem, or because they get as big a headache as I do trying to read through the comments)*, and I'm therefore not getting questions answered if this member responds to them.

I don't believe that it would be appropriate and/or helpful to flag the comments  because there's nothing grossly wrong with a comment when viewed individually, and as far as I understand flags don't affect an individuals privileges.

Is there anything that I can currently do to limit and/or block this member from commenting/answering my posts, and if not, is this something that would be worthwhile considering in the future?

Comment: Nope. Just ignore them.

Comment: If they're knocking at your door, or standing next to you waiting for you to answer and you're ignoring them, *yes*, that's rude. Not replying to their comment on Stack Overflow however, *isn't*.

Comment: @Bart - Don't you think that will make me seem rude and/or uninterested in solving the problem and alienate other members?

Comment: If they are truly not helpful nor constructive, joining the extended comments will only drive your post into the ground. So, no.

Comment: @Matt - LOL He actually keeps reposting every few minutes until I respond ;-) It was a complete nightmare when I made the mistake of agreeing to move the conversation to a chat room :-(

Comment: @ChayaCooper If it's that persistent, flagging might be acceptable.

Comment: @Matt That's nonsense and could well be construed exactly oppositely, in that someone is rude in knocking on _my_ door, or waiting for _me_ to do anything. Context, I say, context. But either way, we each have our own individual privileges.

Comment: @Bart You have no idea how good it is to hear that :-D I think I might even close out those questions and just repost them

Comment: @Matt It's her question, not the other user's.  If she ignores him when he's making sincere clarifying questions then she appears to be an unresponsive OP.  When I notice an unresponsive OP I'm much more likely to walk away from a question early on.

Comment: "He actually keeps reposting every few minutes until I respond" Those definitely sound flaggable.  Also, I'm waiting on someone to show up here and start chatting you up.  ;)

Comment: @ChayaCooper Be careful about that. That might land you into trouble. If the comments are really not constructive and lead nowhere, flag for moderator attention and ask for a comment cleanup.

Comment: @Servy - That's been my concern :-( So what would you recommend?

Comment: @ChayaCooper That would not be appropriate.  Do not repost your questions just because there are is a long comment thread.

Comment: @ChayaCooper If the comments really are constructive then respond.  If they're not, don't.  If it's blatantly obvious that the comments are intended to be harmful or disruptive, then flag.  You'd need to post an example to get into specifics, but if it's really the case that the user is sincerely trying to help you, and they just don't know enough to be able to, then respond to their questions until more knowledgeable users step in.  If it's clear trolling, chances are the other knowledgeable users will pick up on it; don't respond.

Comment: @Servy: My bad, expected the user expecting to nursed through his problem, rather than being (too) willing to help :P

Comment: I can relate. I'm afraid your only options are to either ignore him, or flag his comments and let the moderators handle the situation. Or both. What you shouldn't do, however, is continue a conversation if you don't feel it's worth your time (or worse). Some people _may_ perceive you not responding to a comment as rude, but that's... their problem not yours. We are all here to learn and have a bit of fun, you are under no obligation to answer _every_ comment and participate in _every_ discussion. If the situation has reached a point that annoys you, just ignore and move on.

Comment: @Servy - Is it a problem to repost if I remove the original question? I've sometimes done that if I've changed/edited the question significantly

Comment: @ChayaCooper You should not be reposting a question, ever.  It doesn't matter if your original question is closed, deleted, or just unanswered.

Comment: You guys are awesome :-D

Comment: @BilltheLizard How do you know the person in question isn't already here? And how do we know it isn't you? O_o /paranoia

Comment: @Bart - I didn't even know that I could ask a moderator for a comment cleanup. That would certainly help :-) It's not in the FAQ so any idea how I'd do that?

Comment: @ChayaCooper: You can flag your question with a custom flag and describe the problem there ("This comment thread has X and Y problems...")

Comment: Just flag your post and use the "other" option. Explain the situation. Comments should only be used to clarify and not get out of hand/lengthy. If the situation is extreme, a cleanup is usually no problem. Don't use that flag just for any comments you don't like though. Use it sparingly.

Comment: @Yannis OMG you're right, it could be any one of us!

Comment: @BilltheLizard - I actually avoided posting this for a while because I was afraid of that ;-) He's a sweet guy and really means well, but I wasted over 100 hours in the past 3 weeks dealing with him, and now I just cringe when he joins a comment thread

Comment: Incidentally, if you're worried about his feelings, having some box pop up saying "This user has blocked you from answering or commenting on her posts" would hardly be a good solution anyway...

Comment: @DavidRobinson & Bart - Thank you! That should make a big difference :-D And I don't think you have to worry about my overusing it for anyone else since I obviously haven't used the 'flag' until now (since I didn't even know those options existed)

Comment: @DavidRobinson I know :-( Which is why I've waited to do anything. But to be honest, I'm much more concerned about being seen as rude by other members right now than hurting his feelings

Comment: These answers and comments have been awesome - not only have I found a solution to my problem, but I also laughed and feel much better about something that's been driving me crazy :-D

Comment: @Bart - Thank you! That should make a big difference :-D And I don't think you have to worry about my overusing it for anyone else since I obviously haven't used the 'flag' until now (since I didn't even know those options existed)

Comment: Based on your comment history, it looks like you could avoid a lot of these problems by being better at doing your homework before asking questions. You seem to be confused about a lot of really basic stuff, which often leads to just as much frustration for the answerers as for you, even if they're just trying to help, as you end up talking past eachother.

Comment: @hammar I usually spend a lot of time researching and trying to solve things myself before posting a question (typically bet. 3 - 12 hours) because I truly appreciate how valuable other member's time is. The funny thing is that more often than not, it seems that I would have been better off posting my question sooner ;-) But I'm still somewhat of a beginner and I definitely get confused about basic things each time I get into a new area start dealing with something new - which has definitely been the case for the past few weeks. The good news is that the things that confuse me have changed ;-)

Comment: I downvoted this suggestion because I don't think there should be a way to shut out users from one's questions, but I appreciate your spirit and consideration. Keep it up and please don't be put off by the occasionally rough tone on SO!

Comment: @Pekka웃 That's really sweet of you :-D It took months for me to have the guts to post again after my first 2 experiences, and nothing was quite as rewarding as when the positive feedback far outpaced the negative comments :-) And I'm thrilled that I've finally started being able to occasionally answer questions and help out other people too :-D I probably rave about SO more than anyone else in the NY tech scene because I know that I couldn't possibly have done most of what I'm doing without the awesome SO community :-D

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There isn't a way to block a specific user.

If the pattern of behavior constitutes inappropriate harassment, you should flag the comment or answer for moderator attention (perhaps drawing attention to the user's past behavior in a custom flag). But if it's simply incorrect or unhelpful, just ignore them. (If they provide an answer that is incorrect or unhelpful, as opposed to a comment, you can downvote it).

You seem to be worried that not answering the questions will make you appear rude to other users. The question in that case is whether the user's comments, regardless of their source, are *worth responding to.* If they are, you should be answering them anyway- it doesn't matter who asked them. If they're not, other users will recognize this and won't judge you for ignoring them.

---

As described in the comments, if you have accumulated a long and unhelpful comment thread, you can also flag your post with a custom flag and ask for the comments to be cleaned up by a moderator. Moderators are often happy to clean up long conversations in comments, and it would not lead to any penalty or even notification for the commenters.

Comment: Thank you so much David :-D That's incredibly helpful :-) Since I'm the one who posted the question, I'd like to think that it's a good question ;-) But unfortunately the same can't be said for most of his :-(

Comment: @ChayaCooper: My apologies, the language in my answer must not have been clear (edited to clarify). I was referring to whether his comments were worth responding to, not whether your question is worth answering. If his comments for clarification are about things other people might find useful, you should answer them. If they're entirely irrelevant, no one will judge you for ignoring them.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that :-D I know that I work way too hard when I post questions (both in writing them and in responding to members trying to help me), but I am so appreciative of the SO community and want to do everything I can do make it even more awesome. It would be great if they expanded the voting/flag system to give both positive/neg feedback on specific items/behaviors so that members could learn even more. After all this time, I'm still often guessing about whether or not I've phrased a title or question well or tagged it effectively

Answer (score 6):

Flags are not only for offensive content.
This seems to me like the isolated case for which was invented the text box when you click on other... 
When you click on flag, you get the following options :

[image]

The one you are looking for is `too chatty` or `other` if you can explain why. Either that or you ignore them but I think these are your two only options.

Comment: I'm not too sure a nagging user is "too chatty". I believe that's for when a conversation between members erupts about what they had for tea, and what the weather is like.

Comment: `without contributing anything productive towards answering them` I think it does not have it's place there.

Comment: Maybe we can request additional options of that, as well as repetitive question/comment (which is this users worst offense)

Comment: This *seems* to me like the isolated case for which was invented the text box when you click on `other...`. My opinion though

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk Any chance you could link this screenshot to a larger version? This is kind of difficult to see.

Comment: @Bart I don't know i'm blind...

Comment: You guys are awesome :-D You've both solved my problem and gotten me laughing about it :-D

Comment: @ChayaCooper: Only "other" is worthwhile in this situation.