# Block particular user's comments on my answer on his question

Tags: discussion, comments, abuse

I was in a good mood today and I decided to give an answer on an [unconstructive question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16208207/1313143) that should help the OP underway (one of the *hasn't tried anything, expects code writing service* kind of people). However he keeps posting comments underneath that it is not a full solution etc., and from his behaviour I can deduce that he has little programming skills.

I want to prevent him posting more of the same kind of comments, I've already flagged two of them. Ignoring does not seem to help much. Therefore I would like some way to block further comments on my answer. I don't want to remove my answer since it is still legitimate.

Note: this question is different from: [Way for members to block specific community members from commenting/answering posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177127/183189) Since it concerns blocking a user entirely. My suggestion would confine itself to the scope of a single question.

Comment: Really can't see any reason to block a user. Just ignore the comments. If the inbox items that keep appearing annoys you so much I'm sure there's a user script out there that hide the inbox.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you believe that there are many, many comments that need to be cleaned up, you can flag your own answer and select the "other" option. In the text box, explain the situation, and a moderator will come and clean up the comments.

Comment: Yeah, but the user may eventually come back to post more comments.

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester The moderator can tell the user to stop. Or, you could tell the user to stop as well.

Comment: I have done the latter already. But I'll flag.

Answer (score 19):

We are an open community.

That means - no blocking comments.

Sure, in some extremely rare cases, users abuse features and they can get banned from the site.

But a general blocking of comments on posts - no thanks.

Let this be a lesson to you - don't give answers to unconstructive questions... downvote them instead.

Comment: I meant only the comments this specific user posts, on my specific answer.

Comment: Then there is no need to post here. Flag and move on.

Comment: If it was offered to you, then it would need to be offered to everyone as a feature. Hence, it won't happen for the reasons in Oded's answer.

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester - How would that work then? How would we block commenting from a specific user on a specific answer and not generalize it?

Comment: I was a little confused by OP's question.. I thought he was the poster of that HTML question.. doh

Comment: I don't agree to your last sentence - `don't give answers to unconstructive questions... downvote them instead`. There is, I believe, a badge that may be awarded to a good answer on a bad question. I'm **NOT** a badge hunting kind of member, but the reason they are there is to encourage specific behaviour. That said, I can see why it can be good to answer even downvoted questions, since the answer should be judged on the quality of that answer - not on the quality of the question.

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester - If the question is not constructive but you think you can edit it into a constructive one, do that instead. Unconstuctive questions harm the site - answering them harms it more.

Comment: @Oded fair point. I'll do that.