# Is there a way to block notifications from a particuar post?

Tags: discussion, comments, notifications

Some posts in SO and MSO are really very popular and so much popular that if one participates in such question-answer, he is likely to get notifications for this post for rest of the lifetime of the question. In that case, a participant may feel later not to comment or discuss about the post furthermore. So in that situation, is there anyway to block such notification from coming in future from the same post?

Please note that, I have gone through [Way for members to block specific community members from commenting/answering posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177127/way-for-members-to-block-specific-community-members-from-commenting-answering-po) , but here I want to know about specific post because rather than a user, a post annoys much.

Comment: Are they really *that* annoying though? The most it would do is pop up a red circle in the corner, which you can make go away by simply clicking on it, determining you don't care about the notification, and going back to what you were doing...

Comment: Can you please link to the post that's generating more noise than signal for you? If you're really getting rattled by notifications there might be other problems at play ;)

Comment: @TimPost, Not a very particular post.

Comment: In addition to what @animuson says above; no matter how many replies come in on an individual post, you only get a single notification of posts that were made since your last visit, which mitigates this a good bit more.

Comment: @animuson You get a red circle plus your profile will have "updates" in the tabs. A bit unrelated but those two things should be linked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do this is to delete your participation on the post. If it's someone else's post that you commented on, delete your comments. If it's *your* post, you would have to delete the post itself. Of course, that's not always possible, and is generally not desirable.  But in my opinion, you should want to be notified of replies to your own posts.

I think there's been a request about removing notifications of replies to your own posts, but I'm pretty sure it was declined.